# Does using Integer in loop makes any difference?

Tags: java, for-loop, wrapper, primitive

I've been using `int` in `for-loop`. Like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
     //Do something...
}
```

If I use **`Integer`** instead of **`int`**, like below, does it makes any difference?

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
     //Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will require auto-unboxing and auto-boxing for each iteration. It'll work the same way, and you don't need to *do* anything to make it work, but it's unnecessary and easily avoided.

Also it might *slightly* slow down the loop for no real advantage.

Basically `Integer` should only ever be used when you actually *need* the number to be an `Object` (for example when you put it into a collection, when `null` is a valid value, ...). At all other times, you should use the primitive types where possible (`int`, `char`, ...).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you already know the difference between [`int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).
The loops will behave the same, but using `int` is preferable when you don't need `Integer`. Don't do that, it waste time (Capitalizing the "i" and adding "eger" :)). Furthermore, it's not efficient since [auto-unboxing/auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) will be done on each iteration.

Use `int` when you can live without `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

**I always choose primitive over Wrappers, When ever I can.**

Your code works fine.

But, though very minor difference,

While run time, If we use Wrappers [Boxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.7)  and [Unboxing Conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.8) happens at Runtime,Obviously that takes more time.

> If p is a value of type int, then boxing conversion converts p into a reference r of class and type Integer, such that r.intValue() == p

And vice-versa, this time will be saved in case,if we use `Primitives`.

Answer (score 2):

The only big thing(though I wouldn't do it myself & won't advise you to do that either) I could think about using in such a scenario is

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
     i = null; // Can do this here but not in the other loop
     // Obviously this is not going to be the only line here, unless you wanna get a NPE
     // Just something, which you COULD DO
}
```

Other than this, I really doubt if its going to matter much. Though using `int` is preferred. Also, boxing and auto-boxing for every iteration, is not a good thing(when you can just use `int` directly).

Comment: out of interest, what happens when you `i++` when `i` is `null`? Won't it throw a NullPointerException?

Comment: @Bathsheba three letters... NPE

Comment: @Bathsheba - I said we can do that. Didn't say that it would be the only piece of code in the loop block. I can make it null, have a check on if its null or not, do something else and reassign it a value.

Comment: @Bathsheba You'l end up with NPE.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Integer` will incur a performance cost due to boxing, so use `int`.

However, if you intend to use `i` within the loop body as, say a hash map key, then use the reference type `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) a feature of Java 5, It does not.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not make any difference in functioning. Auto boxing and and auto-unboxing feature helps you with `i++` in the loop

Answer (score -1):

No it won't. `Integer` is a wrapper which adds some functionality to the primitive `int` type. If you are not going to use that functionality, its better to stick to `int`.

In this case it might not make a lot of difference but suppose you were to use say
`Integer[]` instead of `int[]`, then youd be wasting a LOT of memory and speed.

Comment: Missed in the hurry. Corrected.